# Take a column of a matrix and make it a row in kdb

Tags: kdb, q-lang

Consider the matrix:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I'd like to take the middle column, assign it to a variable, and replace the middle row with it, giving me

```
1 2 3
2 5 8
7 8 9
```

I'm extracting the middle column using

```
a:m[;enlist1]
```

which returns

```
2
5
8
```

How do I replace the middle row with a? Is a flip necessary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dot amend -

```
q)show m:(3;3)#1+til 10
    1 2 3
    4 5 6
    7 8 9
q)show a:m[;1]
    2 5 8
q).[m;(1;::);:;a]
    1 2 3
    2 5 8
    7 8 9
```

Can see documentation here:

- http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/DotSymbol
- http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:QforMortals2/functions#Functional_Forms_of_Amend

Comment: Marvellous, thank you. I'm not too familiar with dot amend. I'll do a bit of research. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to update the matrix in place you can use

```
q)show m:(3;3)#1+til 10
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
q)a:m[;1]
q)m[1]:a
q)show m
1 2 3
2 5 8
7 8 9
q)
```

cutting out "a" all you need is:

```
m[1]:m[;1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Making it slightly more generic where you can define the operation, row, and column

```
q)m:3 cut 1+til 9
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Assigning the middle column to middle row :

```
q){[ m;o;i1;i2] .[m;enlist i1;o; flip[m] i2 ] }[m;:;1;1]
1 2 3
2 5 8
7 8 9
```

Adding the middle column to middle row by passing `o` as `+`

```
q){[ m;o;i1;i2] .[m;enlist i1;o; flip[m] i2 ] }[m;+;1;1]
1 2  3
6 10 14
7 8  9
```